# How to code "incorrect" and "correct" answers with optional hints?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

  public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 20);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      // prompting user to enter their desired amount of lives
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Guessing Game! I'll think of a number, and you guess what it is! How many lives do you want to have?");
        double lives = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Great! You have " + lives + " attempts to guess correctly."); //reminder of lives
      
        System.out.print(""Want to enable lower/higher hints? Type "N" or "Y"."");
        // ???

        System.out.print(" Let's begin!");
       // game begin
        int count = 0;     
        while (count <  lives ) {
          System.out.println(" So... what number am I thinking of?");
          double userGuess = input.nextDouble();
          boolean tooHigh = userGuess > number1; // tell user to guess lower
          boolean tooLow = userGuess < number1; // tell user to guess higher

          count++;
   
   
        }
     }
  }
```

I tried using if statements to get solid feedback, but I might have been typing them incorrectly. I tried to code: if userGuess is higher than the randomly generated number1, tell user to guess lower. I also am trying to figure out the hint option: if the user types Y for yes on hints, I use system print to say "guess lower/higher"? Also, the last loop gets stuck in eternity repeatedly asking "So what number am I thinking of?" which is funny, but I need it to say something like "try again!" with no hints and "try again, guess lower" *with* hints.

Here is how I coded my if statements:

```
if (userGuess > number1, userGuess < number1) {
        System.out.print("Try again! You have " + lives + " lives left.")
      }
      else {
        System.out.print("Good job!")
      }
```

Comment: You need to show the `if` statements you tried.

Comment: What do you think the `,` in your if statement does?

Comment: If the random number to match is an `int` type, why are you using `double` as the type for the user guess? Similarly, why is your "lives" variable using a `double`? What would it mean to have, for instance, `3.1415926` lives?...

Comment: Have you actually tried to Search in **StackOverflow** for [Java Number Guessing Game](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Java+Number+Guessing+Game)? You can also go here for a [Runnable Example](https://controlc.com/682fd3b5).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the `lives` variable, I'd recommend you setting it to `int`, instead of `double`. Not that it would change the flow of your code at this moment, but it is not worth storing counters in anything other than `int`.

So, instead of this:

```
double lives = input.nextDouble();
```

Use this:

```
int lives = input.nextInt();
```

I'd recommend doing the same for `userGuess` and `number1` (which are going to be compared). Your randomly generated number is of type `int`, but you are asking the user to provide a `double`. Either change `number1` to `double`, or `userGuess` to `int`, in order to have matching types.

`tooHigh` and `tooLow` are not needed when using if statements. I'm pretty sure you're not limited by memory, but instead of declaring new `boolean` variables, for readability purposes, just write the relational expressions in the `if` statements. In your case:

```
while (count < lives ) {
    System.out.println(" So... what number am I thinking of?");
    int userGuess = input.nextInt();

    if (userGuess > number1) {
        System.out.println("Guess lower!");
    }
    else if (userGuess < number1) {
        System.out.println("Guess higher!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
        break; // Exit while loop. Stop asking for input.
    }
    
    count++;
}
```

I saw that you'd want your user to decide if to allow hints or not, so I'd recommend you declaring a variable of type `boolean`:

```
boolean allowHints;

System.out.print("Want to enable lower/higher hints? Type \"N\" or \"Y\".");
char c = input.next().charAt(0);
if (c == 'Y') {
    allowHints = true;
}
else {
    allowHints = false;
}
```

Now, you're waiting for user input and storing his reponse in `allowHints`, but you're still displaying the hints, no matter what. In your `if` statements from the while loop, also check if hints are allowed, before checking if the guessed value is higher or lower.

```
// Check if the guess is right first. You won't need to display any hints if the user types in the correct answer
if (userGuess == number1) {
    System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
    break;
}
else if (allowHints == true) {
    if (userGuess > number1) {
        System.out.println("Guess lower!");
    else if (userGuess < number1) {
        System.out.println("Guess higher!");
    }
}
```

Or, simply add `allowHints` to your existing `if` statements:

```
if (userGuess == number1) // ...
else if (allowHints == true && userGuess > number1) // ...
else if (allowHints == true && userGuess < number1) // ...
```

Comment: ...and what if the guess is not too high, AND not too low? It must be the guess, right? Add a last `else` block to tell them they correctly guessed and also provide a clean way to exit the `while` loop as the game is over!

Comment: @Idle_Mind Indeed. I, somehow, omitted the fact that he's not checking for correct input. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That'll work, though many would argue that exiting the loop with `break` is not "clean".